# jQuery onPage search with dropdown function

Tags: jquery, directory-tree

I'm creating an on-page search function via jQuery. The search-function should search for a string from an input field. If there aren't any matches, everything should be hidden, if it finds something then it should show the `li` elements with all their parents above.

It looks like this in [live](https://fbb.coserver.ch/deklarationen.html)

This is my code:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    if(filter == '') {
        $("div#jQ-menus ul").not(".is-open, .main").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("div#jQ-menus ul li").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                // if not relevant
                $(this).fadeOut();
            } else {
                // if relevant
                $(this).fadeIn();
                $(this).parents("ul").fadeIn();
                count++;
            }
        });
        var numberItems = count;
    }
});
```

So there is a html output like this:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="main">
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">+ FBB Werk Hinwil 2012</span>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <span class="toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">+ Fundationsschicht</span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">+ Deckschicht</span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Everything great and fine.
But now if I open a tree and then I'm about to search something, it works. and then, if I remove the search-string, it should show the same tree just like before using the search-function.
Here comes the problem. All the `li`'s are not click able anymore. maybe I just have set some classes wrong, or my logic behind this search-function isn't reliable.

I use [directory-tree](http://demo.lateralcode.com/directory-tree/) to create the tree.

Can anyone help here?